# How to display a loop of custom post types in columns

Tags: loop, widgets

hope all is well. I have written a widget that displays posts from a Custom Post Type 'Staff'. Whenever the client adds a new Staff member, their name and featured image is displayed. My question is: How can I get these 'posts' to populate columns? Ideally I would like to have 2 rows of 4 columns. Here is my Widget Code:

```
public function widget($args, $instance) {

    //Arguments that you can pass through the widget function. We are displaying only the CPT 'News' in our widget

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'Staff',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    //Loop through Custom Post Type in there are posts and if we are currently on a single Program page. ('program' must be lowercase) EDIT is_singular is now empty to show on all singular pages in general

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    if($loop->have_posts() && is_singular('')):
        while($loop->have_posts()) {

            $loop->the_post();

            //What will be displayed physically in the widget for each item

            echo '<br />';
            the_title();
            echo '<div class="entry-content">';
            the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
            the_content();
            echo '</div>';


        }endif;


    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is an HTML/CSS question. Your PHP is mostly fine as is. You just need to remove the `<br>` from your code.

Then, in your CSS, use 'float' to make the columns out of the divs. More info https://learn.co/lessons/css-column-structure-using-floats